# jquery ui datepicker not setting dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i am trying to set mindate dynamically on pageload event and dropdown change event also , mindate sets in page load but when i am trying to set on change event it gives error
this is my code
    //basic initialization of datepicker

```
$('#transaction_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: 'today',
    inline: true
});

var fy_start_date = '<?php echo $fy_start_date;?>';

// call function to set mindate on pageload 
setmindate(fy_start_date, 0);

// dropdown change event to call ajax function to set ne mindate value
$('#from_ledger').change(function(){
    var accstartdate = $('#from_ledger').val();
    getstartdate(accstartdate);      
});

// dropdown change event to call ajax function to set ne mindate value
$('#to_ledger').change(function(){
        var accstartdate = $('#to_ledger').val();
        getstartdate(accstartdate);      
   });

//ajax function to set new mindate
function getstartdate(id){
//call function to set new mindtae
                  setmindate(result, 1);
               }

//function to set mindate
function setmindate(min_date, change) {

    var minumum_date = min_date;
    $('#transaction_date').datepicker('destroy');
    $('#transaction_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minumum_date);

    }
});
```

it gives error message Error: cannot call methods on datepicker prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

jquery version 1.11.1
jquery ui version 1.11.4

Comment: Change with it $('#transaction_date').datepicker({ minDate : minumum_date });

Comment: Please give us a little more context

Comment: already try this its not working also i try to destroy before setting new value but it gives an error $('#transaction_date').datepicker('destroy')

Comment: i think its version compatibility issu

Comment: Is it really necessary to call `.datepicker('destroy')` ? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: i want to set new mindate on every drop down change call, so before setting new value i have to empty previous value its not working so i try to destroy it